# @list_route and @detail_route nested routes do not appear in Browseable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use nested routes via `@list_route` and `@detail_route` decorators. The routes work and return data but I must navigate to them manually in the address bar. They do not appear in the `DefaultRouter` generated `ApiRoot` in the browseable API. I am using Django 1.8 and Rest Framework 3.1.1.

In **urls.py**:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'aggregates', viewsets.AggregateViewSet, base_name='aggregate')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls, namespace='myapp')),
]
```

In **viewsets.py**:

```
class AggregateViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.DataAggregate.objects.order_by('id')
    serializer_class = serializers.AggregateSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @list_route(url_path='recent')
    def recent_aggregates(self, request):
        return Response({'message': 'herp a derp'})
```

When I navigate to `/myapp/api`, the browsable API only shows this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "aggregates": "http://localhost:8000/myapp/api/aggregates/"
}
```

I am **expecting** this:

```
{
    "aggregates": "http://localhost:8000/myapp/api/aggregates/"
    "aggregates-recent": "http://localhost:8000/myapp/api/aggregates/recent"
}
```

I have tried various modified versions to see if it will budge, no avail. Again, these routes *do* function and the browseable API will show the pages for them if I navigate to them manually... but defeats the purpose of the browseable api.

I took a peek at the code for `DefaultRouter` (and `SimpleRouter`) and it does appear to discover dynamic routes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true and intended it does not appear in the API by default.

I myself use that snippet to provide nested routes following [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) style (py3 code).

```
import urllib
from collections import OrderedDict

from rest_framework import serializers, relations

class SubNamespaceURLField(relations.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    """Refers to a child namespace of the object, as pointed by view_name
    """
    def __init__(self, namespace, *args, **kwargs):
        self.namespace = namespace.strip('/')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        base = super().field_to_native(obj, field_name)
        return urllib.parse.urljoin(base, self.namespace) + '/'

class HALNestedLinksField(relations.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    """ Tries to represent a list of nested links on the resource a
    HAL-compliant way.

    See http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html
    """
    def __init__(self, endpoints, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param endpoints list of url suffixes leading to nested operations on
                         the resource (ex: ['preview', 'check'])
        """
        self.endpoints = endpoints
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_attribute(self, obj):
        return obj

    def to_representation(self, value):
        links = OrderedDict()
        prefix = super().to_representation(self.get_attribute(value))
        for i in self.endpoints:
            # We consider if it contains a dot its a content-type indication,
            # so no trailing slash
            if '.' in i:
                suffix = ''
            else:
                suffix = '/'
            links[i] = {'href':
                        urllib.parse.urljoin(prefix, i) + suffix}
        return links
```

Then use it in your serializer with :

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    _links = HALNestedLinksField(['revalidate'], # you detail_route names
                                 view_name='somemodel-detail')
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('url',
                  'date',
                  '_links') # do not forget it
```

And you'll get a `_links` attribute with all the related routes you declared in your `HALNestedLinksField`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Ironically enough I have moved to Node for this project, but this is great reference material.